# Connection Refused: Thrift Client on JRuby 1.7.3

Tags: jruby, thrift

I am trying to use a Thrift client on JRuby 1.7.3. The error message is always

```
Could not connect to ::1:55674: Connection refused - Connection refused
```

I can always connect successfully on ruby-1.9.3. After much Googling, it appears that the Thrift client had an issue with JRuby, but it's supposed to be [fixed in 1.6.7](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5165).

How should I fix this? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

I was creating my `Thrift::ServerSocket` using `::1`. MRI clients will work with this (doesn't matter if host is set to `localhost`, `::1`, or `127.0.0.1`. JRuby clients will not, and will complain about refused connections.

Next, I was creating my `Thrift::Client` using `::1`. Again, JRuby doesn't like it.

Changing every thing to `localhost` fixed it. I don't really understand what is going on, but java is clearly using IPv6.

```
>lsof -i :56990
COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4441 codex   31u  IPv6 0t0  TCP localhost:56990 (LISTEN)
java    4441 codex   36u  IPv6 0t0  TCP localhost:56990->localhost:50439 (ESTABLISHED)
java    4875 codex   31u  IPv6 0t0  TCP localhost:50439->localhost:56990 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: Yeah, you might try setting the following from JRuby (or directly in JAVA_OPTS would work too):  `JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`  See the JRuby issue [IPv4 should be preferred to IPv6](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/775) for more detail.